# Command not found and ImportError in Python for OSX

Tags: bash, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have OSX El Captain with installed Python3.5 and Python2.7. 
I have a folder with my python script and functions which I already added to the environment variable PATH and somehow[*] also to sys.path:

```
Project_folder/
- Python/
-- __init__.py
-- batchProc.py (written in Python 3.4)
-- (other python files)
```

I set my PATH with a .bash_profile file:

```
PATH=“/Users/Robyc/Project_folder/Python:${PATH}”
export PATH
```

And the folder it's there:

```
echo $PATH
“/Users/Robyc/Project_Folder/Python:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin”
```

My sys.path variable

```
['/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev', '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/Users/Robyc/Project_Folder/Python', '/Users/Robyc/Project_Folder/']
```

I have two problems which I have the feeling that are linked to each other.

1. if I type bacthProc.py in the terminal I get Command not found. I need to go to ~/Project_folder/Python
2. if I run ~/Project_folder/Python/batchProc.py the code starts but I get ImportError: No module named Python.

I really don't understand what's wrong with my configuration.

[*] my ~/Project_folder was already there before, but I don't remember how I added it... 
My PYTHONPATH is empty. I now used a pth file as suggested in the
   [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) to add my ~/Project_folder/Python folder to the
   sys.path, i.e. I created the following file:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/svn_code.pth
```

which contains:
    /Users/Robyc/Project_folder/Python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I share the solution to the problem.

The problem was, as expected, in the PATH variable: 
the text editor (TextEdit.app) I used to modify the .bash_profile modified the quotation marks ("...") in a way not correctly recognized by the shell. 
This can be actually seen in the path I posted in the question above: the quotation marks shouldn't appear when doing echo $PATH in the terminal. 
As a result the PATH variable was not properly set. That's why it wasn't possible to call python anymore.

Solution: open the bash_profile with nano and modify the quotation marks...
and never use again TextEdit to modify the bash_profile